# Getting issue with yum install php-pear on centos 6

Tags: php, linux

I am getting this issue, plz help with solution.

```
[root@mynginx lib64]# yum install php-pear
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
* base: centos.mirror.secureax.com
* epel: mirror01.idc.hinet.net
* extras: centos.mirror.secureax.com
* updates: centos.mirror.secureax.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pear.noarch 1:1.9.4-4.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli >= 5.1.0-1 for package: 1:php-pear-1.9.4-4.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-27.el6_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5 for package: php-cli-5.3.3-   27.el6_5.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-cli-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
       Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
       Installed: php-common-5.4.26-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.26-1.el6.remi
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-26.el6.x86_64 (base)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-26.el6
       Available: php-common-5.3.3-27.el6_5.x86_64 (updates)
           php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-27.el6_5
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

This because php-pear's Dependencies packages in "remi Repository"  conflict which in centos's system default Repository,that software's version is not corresponding。

so you can delete "remi Repository" which locate in /etc/yum.repos.d/ 
or  uninstall “remi repo” by "rpm -e xxx" command.